# how to insert the multi-select value in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

iam using codeigniter

```
<select id="example-label" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option-3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option-4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="option-5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="option-6">Option 6</option>
</select>`
```

how to insert multi-select value

Comment: show your code. what you tried to do this ?

Comment: Insert it to what would be the first question?

Comment: Using `INSERT` query of course!

Comment: Giving the `<select>` tag a `name="something[]"` attribute would probably be a good start!

Comment: only the last value is inserted

Comment: See previous comment

Comment: how will be the controller and model

Comment: Try yourself before posting here.

Comment: First show your complete code, ask a proper question to get a proper answer. see this link [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<select id="example-label" multiple="multiple" name='youroption[]'>
    <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option-3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option-4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="option-5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="option-6">Option 6</option>
</select>
```

Add This in Your Contoller

```html
<?php
function get_data()
{
$optiondata=$this->input->post('youroption');
var_dump($optiondata);
}
?>
```

or extract using loop

```html
foreach($optiondata as $key=>$value)
{
echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Please dont encourage these obvious ___do it all for me___ questions by actually providing an answer, even an answer as basic as this. Once the OP has tried this they will be back with _the next issue_ and _the next issue after that_ saying _No I want it to do ....._ or _Thats does not work because...._ We call it ___the rabbit hole___ and you are about to fall into one if you are not careful

Comment: i need to insert two or more value in database when selected is it only be inserted as an array can you give me the controller and model