# How to insert multiple invoice values in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form with below layout in codeigniter:

```
<input type="text" name="product">`<input type="text" name="cost">`
```

The form has several rows with the same input names. Have tried several suggestions such as [Batch creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875706/how-to-create-codeigniter-batch-insert-array) and [this thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747337/how-to-insert-the-multi-select-value-in-codeigniter) but not working out

Comment: All inputs are type="text"?

Comment: Yes. All are in type text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array of same textboxes name for batch insert

`insert_batch` function insert multiple data at a time to table in codeigniter

**view page**

```
<form action="<?=base_url('Test_c/insert_data')?>" method="post">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" name="product[]"><input type="text" name="cost[]">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" name="product[]"><input type="text" name="cost[]">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" name="product[]"><input type="text" name="cost[]">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" name="product[]"><input type="text" name="cost[]">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" name="product[]"><input type="text" name="cost[]">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
```

**controller function**

```
function insert_data() {
            $product = $this->input->post('product');
            $cost = $this->input->post('cost');
            $insert_array = array();
            for ($i=0; $i < count($product); $i++) {
                $tmp = array();
                $tmp['product'] = $product[$i];
                $tmp['cost'] = $cost[$i];
                $insert_array[] = $tmp;
            }

            $this->db->insert_batch('test', $insert_array);
            //echo $this->db->last_query();
    }
```

Comment: glad to help you.can you please upvote and accept it.

Comment: Yes I have...this really helped

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="text" name="product[]">
<input type="text" name="cost[]">
```

Controller:

```
function insertData() {
    $product = $this->input->post('product');
    $cost = $this->input->post('cost');

    foreach($product as $key=>$val){

     $data = array(
        'product'     =>$val,
        'cost'  =>$cost[$key]

        );

    }
   $this->db->insert_batch('table_name', $data); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a post array like so:

```
<input type="text" name="product[]">
<input type="text" name="cost[]">
```

Then you can foreach your post and insert_batch or several normal insert();

Comment: I have done this...but when I go to post the data, it picks each array as separate i.e. INSERT INTO tablename(product','cost') VALUES(1,2,3,4,5),(120,115,230,105,100) with the first set being proucts and second set being cost...this results to something else. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

> View

```
 <input type="text" name="product[]"><input type="text" name="cost[]">
```

> Controller

```
$arrayOne = $this->input->post('product'); //array(1,2,4);
$arrayTwo = $this->input->post('cost'); //array(22,44,55);
$c = array_combine($arrayOne,$arrayTwo ); // output:array(1=>22,2=>44,4=>55)

foreach($c as $key=>$val){

  $data = array(
     'product_id' => $key ,
     'cost' => $val 
  );

  $this->db->insert('TABLENAME', $data); 

}
```