# Best Practices for Inserting and Updating Multiple Rows in database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have one Skill from which in user can add more skill of them.

Here is my table of `student_skill`:

```
+------+--------------+--------------------------------------+
| id   | student_id   | skill                                |
+------+--------------+--------------------------------------+
| 1    | 1            | 10                                   |
| 2    | 1            | 3                                    |
| 3    | 2            | 2                                    |
| 4    | 2            | 6                                    |
+------+--------------+--------------------------------------+
```

My Html Form:

```
<form action="<?= base_url('skill/add_new_skill') ?>" method="post">
    Select Skills:
    <select name="skill[]" id="skill" multiple>
      <option value="1">Physics</option>
      <option value="2">Accounting </option>
      <option value="3">Business Activity Monitoring</option>
      <option value="4">Redhat Linux </option>
      // More Skill Options Here 
    </select>  
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**The Problem:**

I don't get that how do I Insert and Update that multiple rows.
I want to use `insert_batch` & `update_batch` to add & update skills.

**What I have Done So far?**

Here is my controller code:

```
//Controller Functions
public function insert_skill(){
    $this->load->model ('skill_model');
    $skill_data = $this->input->post();

    $update_status = $this->skill_model->insert_student_skill($skill_data); 

}

public function update_skills(){
    $this->load->model ('skill_model');
    $skill_data = $this->input->post();

    $update_status = $this->skill_model->update_student_skills($skill_data);    

}

//Model Functions
//Update Skill Model
public function update_student_skills($skill_data){

    //What should i do to update student data
    $this->db->update_batch('student_skill', $skill_data);

}

//Insert Skill Model
public function insert_student_skill($skill_data){

    //What should i do to Insert student data
    $this->db->insert_batch('student_skill', $skill_data);

}
```

> **Problem Case Scenario 1**: If User Select `'Physics','Accounting'` First and In
>   updating process if the user changes the selected options according to
>   `'Physics','Redhat Linux'` How Do I Update Skill in this type of
>   scenario?

Comment: @YamanJain Can you please suggest anything regarding this question?

Comment: [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155566/how-to-insert-multiple-invoice-values-in-codeigniter?answertab=active#tab-top) may be it helps you.

Comment: Note that the surrogate id in this table is redundant

Comment: I have tried your solution, I have added scenario in the question. Insert is done perfectly. but the problem in Updating @Nidhi

Comment: @Strawberry sir, I am not understanding what you are saying. can you please elaborate. thank you.

Comment: You have a functioning PRIMARY KEY on (student_id,skill). So those are the only columns you need

Comment: Ok i get that sir, thanks @Strawberry

Comment: Can you please help me with the **Problem Case Scenario 1**? @Strawberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through below to understand batch process in CI query builder.

> **insert_batch**

When you use `insert_batch` command, First parameter will be `table_name` and second parameter will be insert array.

```
$data = array(
        array(
                'title' => 'My title',
                'name' => 'My Name',
                'date' => 'My date'
        ),
        array(
                'title' => 'Another title',
                'name' => 'Another Name',
                'date' => 'Another date'
        )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('table_name', $data);
```

> **update_batch**
>   When you use `update_batch` command , your first parameter will be `table_name`, second parameter will be array of values with where condition and third parameter will contain `field_name` for where condition.

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'My date 2'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'Another date 2'
   )
);

$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'title');
```

In your case you need to implement login like describe below.

**IN Controller**

IN controller methods you need to pass `user_id` field. Please check below.

```
// Insert Function
$update_status = $this->skill_model->insert_student_skill($skill_data,$user_id); 

// Update Function
$update_status = $this->skill_model->update_student_skills($skill_data,$user_id);
```

**IN Model**

```
// Update Data
public function update_student_skills($skill_data,$user_id){

    $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
    $this->db->delete('student_skill');

    $ins_data = array();
    foreach($skill_data as $i => $skills):
        $ins_data[$i]['user_id'] = $user_id;
        $ins_data[$i]['skill_id'] = $skills['skill_id'];
    endforeach;

    $this->db->insert_batch('student_skill', $ins_data);

}

//Insert Skill Model
public function insert_student_skill($skill_data,$user_id){

    $ins_data = array();
    foreach($skill_data as $i => $skills):
        $ins_data[$i]['user_id'] = $user_id;
        $ins_data[$i]['skill_id'] = $skills['skill_id'];
    endforeach;

    $this->db->insert_batch('student_skill', $ins_data);

}
```

Please modify above code depends on your requirement.

Comment: I have tried your solution, I have added scenario in the question. Insert is done perfectly. but the problem in Updating.

Comment: Show your errors and please mention your where condition.

Comment: Got it. In your case the easiest way is first you need to remove all skills for that user and than again insert. `$this->db->where('user_id',$user_id); $this->db->delete('student_skill');` and then `$this->db->insert_batch('student_skill', $ins_data);`

Comment: it is a workaround, so basically, `update_batch` is not gone use in this case. is this best practice to do?

Comment: I think this is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: I have accepted your answer because it gives the perfect result what I want but I am still not convinced with delete and re-inserting of row.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should have a id of current user by session. So you can target row by id to make make changes.

your view.

```
<form action="<?= base_url('skill/update_skill') ?>" method="post">
    Select Skills:
    <select name="skill[]" id="skill" multiple>
      <option value="1">Physics</option>
      <option value="2">Accounting </option>
      <option value="3">Business Activity Monitoring</option>
      <option value="4">Redhat Linux </option>
      // More Skill Options Here 
    </select>  
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Controller

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Skill extends CI_Controller {

      function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('skill_model');
      }

      public function index(){
        $this->load->view('/your_view');
      } // end index function

      function update_skill(){
         $value = $this->input->post('skill');
         $data['skill'] = $value; //it's mean value or rows skill will be inserted/updated

         $current_user_id = '1'; // example: current user id is 1 (set it by session). this is shuold in new Stackoverflow question

         // Now send data and id to model
         $this->skill_model->update_data($data, $current_user_id);
      }

    } // end Class
```

Model

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Skill_model extends CI_Model{

function update_data($data, $current_user_id){
       $this->db->where('id', '$current_user_id');
       $this->db->update('student_skill', $data);

       //after done, if want do something put codes below.
       redirect(site_url('skill')); //example, after done update, redirect user to mysite.com/skill

} // end update_date()


/* you can add another function in this model. maybe will used from another controller 

function another($fromanother){
}

*/

} // end Class
```